# Is there any way to block spam in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, spam-prevention

I am getting unwanted spam in the "Shared with Me" section of my Google Drive. Is there any way to disconnect that portion of the Drive or block the spam?

Comment: There must have been a corresponding email message. What happened to them? Did you mark them as spam?

Comment: @AlE. The email is optional.

Comment: See [Report a violation - Google Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2463296?hl=en)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't disable the section, but you can *report* the spam.

Unfortunately you have to open the file first (much of the Google Drive spam I get I would never want to open). Burried in Google's documentation is:

[image: Google Drive SPAM Unwanted Sharing Instructions]

Answer (score 2):

On a recent discussion on the Official Google Drive forum, a Community Specialist recommend to send feedback to Google directly from Google Drive.

The path to send feedback have slighted change

1. Go to https://drive.google.com
2. Click on Help (the button with the question mark `?` icon)
3. Click on Send Feedback
4. Fill out the form and submit it

Reference

- [Spam on Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/forum/AAAAOxCWsToAgExGtqUg10?hl=en)